# Position of normal to the free surface of a liquid

Tags: gravity, fluid-statics

If the free surface of a liquid resting in an inertial frame is horizontal. Does the normal to the free surface pass through the centre of the earth.
I wonder what will be the outcome if the liquid is kept somewhere else other than equator and pole..
Does it also depend upon the density of that liquid?

Answer (score 1):

On an ideal spherical rotating Earth an mass $m$ on the Earth is subjected to the gravitational attractive force $\frac{GMm}{R^2}$ which provides the force required to make the mass move in a circular path $mR\omega^2$ and the force the object exerts on the surface of the Earth $mg$.

[image]

The force the mass exerts on the Earth has a direction which is not towards the centre of the Earth except when the object is at the poles or on the Equator.

The surface of a liquid will be at right angles to the direction of $mg$ and so the normal to the liquid (and the direction of a plumb line) will not point towards the centre of the Earth.

[image]

The surface of the Earth is itself approximately at right angle to $mg$ and has the shape of an oblate spheroid so when you use you plumb line or tube with water in it to gauge the horizontal, that horizontal will be locally approximately a tangent to the Earth's surface.